Is it possible to restart an azure kubernete pod running a function script?
I am working on a project, and I need that every time that my application calls my azure function this functions somehow restart a pod in kubernetes and I am not sure on how to do this, I was thinking on running a script with a  function that restart this pod, but I don't know how to setup my function to do this or if this is possible.
I am new in azure so every help conuts. thank you
I was trying using the SDK in the function but I am not able to connect to the closter, i am getting
 DefaultAzureCredential acquired a token from EnvironmentCredential

[2024-09-20T03:41:52.511Z] C:\Users\Andres_Sanchez1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1061: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'abccall-demo-lgq05iz2.hcp.eastus.azmk8s.io'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
[2024-09-20T03:41:52.514Z]   warnings.warn(
[2024-09-20T03:42:04.837Z] Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002835461E050>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')': /api/v1/namespaces/eks_demo/pods
[2024-09-20T03:42:08.923Z] 401
[2024-09-20T03:42:08.923Z] Unexpected error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/namespaces/eks_demo/pods (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002835461E9D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
[2024-09-20T03:42:08.928Z] {'kind': 'Status', 'apiVersion': 'v1', 'metadata': {}, 'status': 'Failure', 'message': 'Unauthorized', 'reason': 'Unauthorized', 'code': 401}

I am able to get the credentials from azure but i am not able to communicate with the cluster, here is my function code:
import logging
import os
import azure.functions as func
from kubernetes import client, config
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
import requests
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Processing a request to restart a Kubernetes pod using managed identity.')

    # Get pod name and namespace from query parameters
    pod_name = req.params.get('pod_name')
    namespace = req.params.get('namespace', 'default')

    if not pod_name:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please pass a pod_name in the query string.",
            status_code=400
        )

    try:
        # Use ManagedIdentityCredential for managed identity authentication
        credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

        # Get the AKS API server endpoint from environment variables
        aks_api_server = 'https://abccall-demo-lgq05iz2.hcp.eastus.azmk8s.io' # Set this in your Function App settings
        if not aks_api_server:
            return func.HttpResponse("AKS_API_SERVER environment variable is not set.", status_code=500)

        # Get the access token
        token = credential.get_token("https://management.azure.com/.default").token

        # Create a Kubernetes API client configuration
        configuration = client.Configuration()
        configuration.host = aks_api_server
        configuration.verify_ssl = False  # Consider enabling SSL verification in production
        configuration.api_key = {"authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}

        response = requests.get(f"{aks_api_server}/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods", verify=False)  # Change verify=True in production

        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.json())
        # Create the Kubernetes API client
        k8s_client = client.CoreV1Api(client.ApiClient(configuration))

        v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
        pods = v1.list_namespaced_pod(namespace)

        for pod in pods.items:
            print(f"Pod Name: {pod.metadata.name}")
        # Delete the pod to trigger a restart
        logging.info(f"Attempting to restart pod {pod_name} in namespace {namespace}.")
        k8s_client.delete_namespaced_pod(pod_name, namespace, body=client.V1DeleteOptions())

        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"Pod {pod_name} in namespace {namespace} has been restarted.",
            status_code=200
        )

    except ApiException as e:
        logging.error(f"Exception when calling CoreV1Api->delete_namespaced_pod: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"Error: {str(e)}",
            status_code=e.status
    )
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"Error: {str(e)}",
            status_code=500
    )

I expect to be able to connect to the cluster and restart my pod

You need to assign managed identity to the function with sufficient permissions in the AKS cluster. Since you've already written a Python function to restart the pod, once your cluster is created, create a system-assigned managed identity for Azure Function.
az storage account create --name arkofunctionstorage --resource-group arkorg --location eastus --sku Standard_LRS


az functionapp create \
    --resource-group arkorg \
    --consumption-plan-location eastus \
    --runtime python \
    --functions-version 4 \
    --name MyK8sFunctionApp \
    --storage-account arkofunctionstorage \
    --os-type Linux \
    --assign-identity


assign the necessary role (Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Cluster Admin role) to the Azure Function's managed identity
az functionapp identity show --name MyK8sFunctionApp --resource-group arkorg --query principalId --output tsv


az role assignment create --assignee 1234-79f2-abcd-5678-54xyzc \
    --scope /subscriptions/abcd-efg-hijk-lmnop-uvwxyz/resourcegroups/arkorg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/myAKSCluster \
    --role "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Cluster Admin"


Next, create a Cluster Role and Role Binding so that the managed identity has the necessary permissions to interact with the pods.
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: function-app-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "delete"]

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: function-app-binding
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: function-app-role
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: 13f2b02a-79f2-47c5-9ad5-54f7a35e30fc
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io



Now use your Azure Function code to restart the Kubernetes pod. The issue in the code you shared is the authentication part and ensuring SSL verification for the AKS API server communication. below is the updated one
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from kubernetes import client, config

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        # Get pod name and namespace from query parameters
        pod_name = req.params.get('pod_name')
        namespace = req.params.get('namespace', 'default')

        if not pod_name:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "Please pass a pod_name in the query string.",
                status_code=400
            )

        
        aks_api_server = 'https://myakscluster-dns-ieevn5ni.hcp.eastus.azmk8s.io'
        
        # Get token using managed identity
        credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
        token = credential.get_token("https://management.azure.com/.default").token

        
        configuration = client.Configuration()
        configuration.host = aks_api_server
        configuration.verify_ssl = True  
        configuration.api_key = {"authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}
        
        
        k8s_client = client.CoreV1Api(client.ApiClient(configuration))

        
        logging.info(f"Attempting to restart pod {pod_name} in namespace {namespace}.")

        # Restart pod by deleting it
        k8s_client.delete_namespaced_pod(pod_name, namespace, body=client.V1DeleteOptions())

        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"Pod {pod_name} in namespace {namespace} has been restarted.",
            status_code=200
        )
    except client.ApiException as e:
        logging.error(f"Exception when calling CoreV1Api->delete_namespaced_pod: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"Error: {str(e)}",
            status_code=e.status
        )
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"Error: {str(e)}",
            status_code=500
        )


build it and run it


The function deletes the specified pod, which will trigger k8s to recreate the pod


Thanks for your help, I am getting this error when I run the function:
2024-09-21T00:26:33Z   [Error]   Exception when calling CoreV1Api->delete_namespaced_pod: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '02569b7f-a742-4d4b-a1dd-6ee789209264', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Sat, 21 Sep 2024 00:26:33 GMT', 'Content-Length': '129'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}
Did I miss something?

Also when I set ssl true I get unable to get local issuer certificate
